# Fantasy book about a princess, a travelling gypsy and the gypsy's mute servant

Tags: story-identification

I've been searching for a old fantasy book for quite some time now and desperately hoping that someone recognizes it.

The book starts out describing a princess of a kingdom - how her family is infamously small statured and has gilden colored skin. The kingdom is peaceful and prosperous and is renowned as a sort of diplomatic place.

They welcome in this travelling gypsy and her servant (a mute boy without his tongue) of sorts who was seeking refudge. Under guise of a merchant, this woman begins selling trinkets and oddities that corrupt peoples minds. Slowly, more and more of these gypsies move into the kingdom, causing the locals to sort of go a bit mad – rioting, refusing to work, etc etc. The kingdom practically rots itself from the inside. Seeing that the kingdom is now weak, a neighboring country invades, furthering to destruction of the kingdom.

The princess is told to escape. She uses an old escape tunnel in the courtyards water well, which takes her outside the walls. She seeks out some old man that was friendly to the kingdom who tells her that the only way to combat the gypdy and her corruption is to change the past with the help of the time master - a man who has the jewel/gem/gemstone that has power to control the flow of time (singular time zone). it turns out that the gypsy has a gem that warps people, making greed engulf them. the princess needs to travel to the top of the world to find out who has control over this thing. On the way, the servant boy just sort of appears and follows her, saving her a few times.

A dragon made of stones greets her at the top of the world and sends her into a cave to seek the time rock because it has no master. It gives her a red stone to light the way and 24hrs otherwise she will be forever stuck in the cave. She realizes that the red stone is in fact the time jewel.

Frustrated with being unable to find the time master, She tried to change the night when the gypsy entered the kingdom, but failed multiple times. Finally, she pushes right back into mute boys past, finding where the gypsy had kidnapped the boy To defeat her.

Comment: I think this is a request looking for the same book:
http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69235/looking-for-young-adult-fantasy-book-where-a-princess-with-gilded-skin-must-c#autocomment235351

Comment: The OP appears to be the same for both this question and the marked duplicate and the two questions are about the same story, so I've closed this.